# when refreshing, it returning The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, azure-web-app-service, nuxt3

I deployed a Nuxt 3 website as a classic SPA since I don't need SSR for my project. Used `nuxt generate` and deployed the contents from `.output/public/` in Azure static web app. It is successfully running now, but when I'm accessing pages with dynamic routes like `user/[id]` and hit refresh the page, I'm getting this message:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

nuxt.config.ts

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: false,
});
```

I'm just really new on Nuxt and in Vue world will appreciate any help guys.

Comment: Your web server is not configured correctly? It actually looks for that URL, instead of just serving your index file.

Comment: in the build file, it actually has `user/index.html` so I'm expecting it to work. I also made the ssr to false during the generate.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-nuxtjs) and able to run the `Nuxt JS` app without any issues.

Make sure you have followed the same steps as below.

- Navigate to the [GitHub](https://github.com/staticwebdev/nuxt-3-starter/generate) and create a new repository from `nuxt-3-starter`.

[image]

- New repo with code will be generated.
  [image]
- In `Azure Portal`, create a new `Static Web App`.

[image]

- Select the GitHub and provide the Repository and branch details as shown below.

[image]

- We can also check the `Workflow file`.

***My Workflow:***

```cs
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: true
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_MANGO_PLANT_0E617661E }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
         ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "/" # App source code path
          api_location: ".output/server" 
          output_location: ".output/public" # Built app content directory 
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_MANGO_PLANT_0E617661E }}
          action: "close"
```

- Make sure the build and deployment are successful. We can check it in `GitHub Repository` =>  `Actions`.

[image]

- Click on the Workflow file, you can see the Jobs Status.

[image]

***OutPut:***

`With dynamic routes -  user/[id]`

[image]

[image]

Please Check the code in my [GitHub](https://github.com/HarshithaVeeramalla/nuxt-3-12Dec) Repository.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have set may `ssr: false` in my nuxt.config.ts which I need on my project. I just curious if you also make the ssr to false will it still works?

Comment: Yes,I have checked by setting `ssr:false`. It is working same as before.

Comment: Please check my GitRepo once.[SSR](https://github.com/HarshithaVeeramalla/nuxt-3-12Dec/blob/main/nuxt.config.ts)

Comment: Already saw that SSR was now set to false, thanks. Btw I couldn't find the dynamic route: `components/User/[id].vue` on your repo. It's supposed to be folder-based, right?